# Posting data to a HTTPS page

Tags: ssl, https, http-post

If I have a page outside of my site, and it posts to an HTTPS page on my site (SSL is setup), will the server and client exchange keys before the data is posted and then encrypt the data, or will the data be posted in plain text from the client to the server, then be given the key to encrypt?

Thank you,

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116049/if-i-submit-a-form-to-a-https-url-from-a-http-url-will-the-form-data-be-encrypt

Comment: thanks for directing me to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data will be encrypted. For an explanation take a look at the answer provided in the duplicate post.